# Creating a Facebook event whose date is after Daylight Savings Time ends: What UTC offset should be used?

Tags: facebook, timezone, timezone-offset

Question: **If I add an event using the Facebook API today (offset UTC-4 at my location) for an event that occurs in December (offset UTC-5 at my location), will it appear correctly? Or do I have to submit it as UTC-5 in order for it to appear correctly in December, but (possibly) incorrectly now?**

Further Details:

On August 1, 2012, Facebook announced that timezone support would be added to events, including through the developer API. [In this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support/), they explain how the changes affect reading and writing events.

**For the writing of events, you are now required to include the UTC offset when defining the start_time and end_time.** So, if I was in Washington, DC (Eastern Timezone and currently on Eastern Daylight Time) and created an event for today, I would input UTC-4. However, if I am creating an event today, and the event date is December 1 (after Daylight Savings Time ends), would I input **UTC-4 (the current offset)** or **UTC-5 (the relevant offset on December 1)**?

I realize that there are a lot of questions about Facebook and timezones, but the ones I have found were written before Facebook announced the new timezone support, and so they don't appear to be relevant to this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have seen, you should be entering the event with the correct UTC offset for the event time you are setting.

For instance, if you had an event in New York City that began at 7pm on 11/3/12 and ended at 7am on 11/4/12 (DST ends at 2am on 11/4/12 in the USA), you would set the start time as `2012-11-03T19:00:00-04:00` and the end time as `2012-11-04-T07:00:00-05:00`.

Facebook *should* display the times corrected for DST.

Comment: Thanks @cpilko. I will post an update here once we have done some testing. Also, I have made a note to double-check my Facebook events when I wake up on 11/4 :)

Comment: I monitored the Facebook API for months after the announced timezone changes, and found that those changes never went into effect!